# reading object from session using Shims/stub in unit test C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, shim, stubs

I have an mvc application .I need to write unit test cases for that application.
In controllers of this application i m reading an object from session

```
 objectclass Obj = (objectclass)Session["Object"];
```

I  need to fake this reading of object using Shims/Stubs .

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: At first, you should learn [how to write your code in a testable way](http://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to access session data and mock the same like this.
Create an interface.

```
interface ISessionHelper
{
    object GetSessionValue(string key);        

}
```

Now you can mock away the method call using any mocking framework.

```
Mock<ISessionHelper> sessionobj = new Mock<ISessionHelper>();
            sessionobj.Setup(a=>a.GetSessionValue(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new object());
```

Replace you seesion access code with

```
ISessionHelper obj = new SessionHelper();
obj.GetSessionValue("Object");
```

Comment: Much cleaner approach.